# Почему у многих новых участников нету аватарки, а вместо нее значок "картинка не найдена"?

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Вот примеры таких участников:

- [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411657/%d0%ae%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9)
- [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411902/miramistin)
- [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411418/%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82)
- [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411452/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be)
- [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411799/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2-%d0%95%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)
- [6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/411719/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b2)
- etc.

Это баг???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все аватарки по приведённым ссылкам - из гугла. Засим возможны 3 варианта:

1. Что-то сломалось в части авторизации на Stackoverflow (маловероятно)
2. Что-то сломалось у гугла в части отдачи аватарок юзеров (вероятно)
3. В API гугла что-то поменялось в части отдачи аватарок юзеров без поддержки обратной совместимости (вероятно)